# How to dynamically infer the class type?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, apache-beam

I am trying to dynamically convert a Json data source to a proto message in apache beam pipeline.

At runtime, user of the pipeline will provide the Json source and the output proto name. In my example code, I have used "com.foo.Bar" as the sample output proto.

Question?

How do I infer the Type parameter "Bar" from the builder variable, so that I can use it to replace the `PCollection<T>` as `PCollection<Bar>` at runtime.

```
Class barClass = Class.forName("com.foo.Bar");

Method newBuilderMethod = barClass.getMethod("newBuilder");
Message.Builder builder = (Message.Builder) newBuilderMethod.invoke(null);

PCollection<Bar> barPCollection =
    pipeline
        .begin()
        .apply(Create.of(some_json_data))
        .apply(JsonToProtoConverter.of(Bar.getDefaultInstance()))
        .setCoder(ProtoCoder.of(Bar.class));
```

Comment: It kind of feels like you're going about this the wrong way. Can you not create a `public Bar(String json) { ... }` for constructing `Bar` instances off of JSON, with appropriate throws if the JSON passed doesn't make sense for that class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want a generic converter that takes a JSON data source and corresponding output proto and accordingly coverts it. Your approach will require adding a new method every time a new json to proto conversion is introduced.

Comment: Sure but that's ... a good thing? Untyped conversion basically bakes a bug surface into your software, explicit constructors don't? (that's the main reason to use a strongly typed language, after all)

Comment: I agree but my use case requires this, I understand the pitfall but this is how we intend to do this. thanks!

Comment: that's fair enough.

Comment: If the code truly works on a generic message type, won't it be enough to refer to it as `Message`?